# mysql query for different section of same report (aggregate and detail )

Tags: mysql, sql, report, aggregate

I am working on SQL query to establish report layout. I have all the required data summarized but i cant think of a way to have **section A and section B side by side** using SQL. Both section have are from same table and can be joined using same key. tot_count is aggregated measure of individual count (ind_count). Is this possible using a mysql query ?

```
-------- section A --------    -------- section B --------
tot_count  empid  ind_count    tot_count  empid  ind_count
3323       XX          2466    101        DD            40
           AA           835               CC            36
           YY            22               EE            11
                                          LL             7
                                          OTHERS         7
```

Comment: Do you have to do this in SQL? I'm sure it's possible, but convoluted. It would be much prettier in application code.

Comment: @JohnTseng: Yes that is the requirement; When you say application code are you saying some kind of reporting tool or java code ?

Comment: I'm talking about the code that makes this database call, preferably Java (or other programming language) code.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can introduce row number into A and B section. E.g.

```
SELECT @ROW := @ROW + 1 AS row, first_name
FROM users, (SELECT @ROW := 0) r;
```

Then

```
SELECT
  A.tot_count as tot_countA,
  A.emptid as emptidA,
  A.ind_count as ind_countA,
  B.tot_count as tot_countB,
  B.emptid as emptidB,
  B.ind_count as ind_countB,
FROM
(subquery A with row column) A inner join
(subquery B with row column) B on A.row=b.row
```

Comment: i tried something similar -                                          `select a.*, b.* from (SELECT @ROW := @ROW + 1 AS row,  nr.* 
FROM tmp_nr_pay nr, (SELECT @ROW := 0) r )  a  inner join 
(SELECT @ROW := @ROW + 1 AS row,  cr.*
FROM tmp_cr_pay cr, (SELECT @ROW := 0) r )  b on a.row=b.row`        but doesn't seem to bring back any rows; The individual sub queries return the row ( 1 - 5 ) from both tables.

Comment: It could be problem of double using the same variable @ ROW. Try to declare another variable e.g. @ ROW1 in the second subquery.

Comment: changing the row works however now it appears as if the 2 sections are unrelated. I mean say if there was 2 rows from section A and 4 rows from section B for same input key joining by row does not display them accordingly .

Comment: Can you also handle the case when COUNT(A) <> COUNT(B)?